# iOS 9 Black keyboard broken layout

Tags: ios, ios9, custom-keyboard

In iOS 9 if I show the camera with a keyboard showing, when I dismiss the camera controller and the keyboard comes back, the layout is broken like in the screenshot below.

Step to reproduce:

1. Tap on a text field, so the keyboard will show
2. Open a controller that uses the camera
3. Dismiss camera controller
4. When the keyboard comes back, it's broken

[image]

Comment: Can you please add code for how you dismiss the keyboard and how you start camera and dismiss it?

Comment: It seem Apple bug, you can fire a bug to Apple.

Comment: i'm having the same problem. Some idea for fix?

Answer (score 4):

The keyboard will not exhibit this behavior if you explicitly call

```
resignFirstResponder()
```

on your UITextField/UITextView before presenting the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Yeah, instead I resolved calling [self.view endEditing:YES];, but I would like to know if its an Apple bug or if in iOS 9 there some rules to follow

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bug, cause I don't see similar behaviour in iOS < 9